# When does LASSO fail?

Tags: lasso

When does LASSO fail in terms of:

1. out of sample forecasting?
2. selecting relevant variables?

(If there is a distinction between 1 and 2 to begin with.)

Also,

3. Under what conditions would one be better off using ridge regression or other techniques instead of LASSO?

I am looking for the most salient examples and conditions which should ring a bell for an applied modeller.

Comment: From the top of my head, I remember reading about LASSO failing in cases when covariates are highly correlated. Source: Trevor Hastie et al.,  "Statistical Learning with Sparsity" https://www.crcpress.com/Statistical-Learning-with-Sparsity-The-Lasso-and-Generalizations/Hastie-Tibshirani-Wainwright/p/book/9781498712163

Comment: @xeon, that is what the answer by Scortchi says in the linked thread. Good that you agree.

Comment: I accidentally found more similar threads. One http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140544 Two http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7935 Could you review them and check if they perhaps should be closed as duplicates (or maybe merged), or edited to make the titles more distinct?