# Why is best subset selection not favored in comparison to lasso?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, lasso, bias-variance-tradeoff

I'm reading about best subset selection in the Elements of statistical learning book. 
If I have 3 predictors $x_1,x_2,x_3$, I create $2^3=8$ subsets:

1. Subset with no predictors
2. subset with predictor $x_1$
3. subset with predictor $x_2$
4. subset with predictor $x_3$
5. subset with predictors $x_1,x_2$
6. subset with predictors $x_1,x_3$
7. subset with predictors $x_2,x_3$
8. subset with predictors $x_1,x_2,x_3$

Then I test all these models on the test data to choose the best one.

> Now my question is why is best subset selection not favored in
>   comparison to e.g. lasso?

If I compare the thresholding functions of best subset and lasso, I see that the best subset sets some of the coefficients to zero, like lasso.
But, the other coefficient (non-zero ones) will still have the ols values, they will be unbiasd. Whereas, in lasso some of the coefficients will be zero and the others (non-zero ones) will have some bias. 
The figure below shows it better: 
[image]

From the picture the part of the red line in the best subset case is laying onto the gray one. The other part is laying in the x-axis where some of the coefficients are zero. The gray line defines the unbiased solutions. In lasso, some bias is introduced by $\lambda$. From this figure I see that best subset is better than lasso! What are the disadvantages of using best subset?

Comment: .. and what do the curves look like when the randomness in the data causes you to select one of the many wrong subsets and the associated coefficient estimates are far from zero relative to their standard errors?

Comment: @jbowman I don't understand it very clearly, why would the randomness in the data cause me to select the wrong one? If I would use cross validation to select the best subset, I would then have smaller chances to select the wrong subset.

Comment: You seem to be equating "less bias" with "better".  What brings you to place such a high value on unbiasedness?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In subset selection, the nonzero parameters will only be unbiased if you have chosen a superset of the correct model, i.e., if you have removed *only* predictors whose true coefficient values are zero. If your selection procedure led you to exclude a predictor with a true nonzero coefficient, *all* coefficient estimates will be biased. This defeats your argument if you will agree that selection is typically not perfect.

Thus, to make "sure" of an unbiased model estimate, you should err on the side of including more, or even all potentially relevant predictors. That is, you should not select at all.

Why is this a bad idea? Because of the bias-variance tradeoff. Yes, your large model will be unbiased, but it will have a large variance, and the variance will dominate the prediction (or other) error.

Therefore, it is better to accept that parameter estimates *will* be biased but have lower variance (regularization), rather than hope that our subset selection has only removed true zero parameters so we have an unbiased model with larger variance.

Since you write that you assess both approaches using cross-validation, this mitigates some of the concerns above. One remaining issue for Best Subset remains: it constrains some parameters to be exactly zero and lets the others float freely. So there is a discontinuity in the estimate, which isn't there if we tweak the lasso $\lambda$ beyond a point $\lambda_0$ where a predictor $p$ is included or excluded. Suppose that cross-validation outputs an "optimal" $\lambda$ that is close to $\lambda_0$, so we are essentially unsure whether p should be included or not. In this case, I would argue that it makes more sense to constrain the parameter estimate $\hat{\beta}_p$ via the lasso to a small (absolute) value, rather than either completely exclude it, $\hat{\beta}_p=0$, or let it float freely, $\hat{\beta}_p=\hat{\beta}_p^{\text{OLS}}$, as Best Subset does.

This may be helpful: [Why does shrinkage work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/179864/1352)

Comment: Hmm. I don't think this answers why best subset is worse than lasso (which is the main question here).

Comment: @amoeba: would you like to elaborate?

Comment: Well, I understood the question as asking why lasso is preferred to best subset. Imagine we put both in a cross-validation loop, and then either tune the lasso parameter or find the best subset. The lasso is usually recommended. I understood the question as asking *Why?* (see e.g. the title of the Q) and I am not sure your answer actually answers that. Or did I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: @amoeba: I did try to answer that question. The OP argued that Best Subset will give unbiased estimates conditional on selecting a subset that encompasses the true model. My argument is that (a) we can't be sure of that, so we may indeed have bias, so (b) we have an incentive to use rather a larger than a smaller subset, but then (c) the bias-variance tradeoff kicks in, and the larger variance dominates the unbiasedness. Lasso trades an increase in bias against a reduction in variance, which may be better. I believe that this sufficiently answers the question. Am I missing something?

Comment: (I'll be traveling the next couple of days, so I may be unresponsive.)

Comment: The procedure suggested by OP is to select the "best subset" on the test data. This should take care of the bias-variance tradeoff; small subsets have high bias and low variance, large subsets have low bias but high variance. But we use the test data to find the sweet spot (exactly like when we are tuning lasso). I don't see how "an incentive to use rather a larger than a smaller subset" is relevant here; the suggestion is to use the subset that will perform best on the validation data. Presumably it will have some optimal size, not too small and not too big.

Comment: @amoeba: you have a point. I overlooked the part about the test data. One could start arguing about overfitting on the test data, but otherwise, a holdout or CV type approach is of course better than, say, stepwise approaches to finding the "best" subset.

Comment: One remaining issue for Best Subset is that it constrains some parameters to be exactly zero and lets the others float freely, so there is a discontinuity in the estimate, which isn't there if we tweak the lasso $\lambda$ beyond a point $\lambda_0$ where a predictor $p$ is included or excluded. I'd argue that if we are essentially unsure whether $p$ should be included or not, because $\lambda\approx\lambda_0$, then it makes more sense to constrain the parameter estimate $\hat{\beta}_p$ via the lasso, rather than let it float freely.

Comment: Agree that this answer doesn't really answer the question - I've added my take on this below...

Comment: The point is that "best subset" is essentially equivalent to L0 penalty (as @Tom wrote in his answer), and lasso is L1 penalty. So what the question really asks (admittedly in disguise) is why L1 is preferred to L0. You now put forward some argument in your last comment, but your answer itself as it is currently written does not answer the question at all. I suggest you edit it.

Comment: Still added a bit more detail in my answer with some extra references to some relevant work...

Comment: This is getting interesting. Thanks everyone. I'll put this thread in my to do list and address it next week when I'm back from traveling - right now, I don't have the spare bandwidth I should devote to this.

Comment: @amoeba: thanks once more. I did edit my answer, but I still don't see that "my answer itself as it is currently written does not answer the question at all". We may need to disagree here.

Answer (score 24):

In principle, if the best subset can be found (i.e. for large enough datasets or if the solution is extremely sparse or if there are nonnegativity constraints which can help to identify the best subset), it is indeed better than the LASSO, in terms of (1) selecting the variables that actually contribute to the fit, (2) not selecting the variables that do not contribute to the fit, (3) prediction accuracy and (4) producing essentially unbiased estimates for the selected variables. One recent paper that argued for the superior quality of best subset over LASSO is that by [Bertsimas et al (2016) "Best subset selection via a modern optimization lens"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.03133). Another older one giving a concrete example (on the deconvolution of spike trains) where best subset was better than LASSO or ridge is that by [de Rooi & Eilers (2011).](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0003267011006696) (Well that one actually approximates best subset using an iterative adaptive ridge regression approach as in [Frommlet & Nuel (2016)](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0148620) and as used in my [L0glm package](https://github.com/tomwenseleers/L0glm/blob/master/benchmarks/benchmarks%20multichannel%20deconvolution%20gaussian%20L0glm%20abess%20glmnet.R) that is in development)

The reason that the LASSO is still preferred in practice is mostly due to it being computationally much easier to calculate and the coefficient paths being quite stable. Best subset selection, i.e. using an $L_0$ pseudonorm penalty, is often seen as a combinatorial problem, and is then NP hard, whereas the LASSO solution is convex and easy to calculate over a regularization path using pathwise coordinate descent. In fact, the LASSO ($L_1$ norm penalized regression) is the tightest convex relaxation of $L_0$ pseudonorm penalized regression / best subset selection and so is uniquely defined (bridge regression, i.e. $L_q$ norm penalized regression with q close to 0 would in principle be closer to best subset selection than LASSO, but this is no longer a convex optimization problem, and so is [quite tricky to fit](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/303408845_Piece-wise_quadratic_approximations_of_arbitrary_error_functions_for_fast_and_robust_machine_learning)).

To reduce the bias of the LASSO one can use derived multistep approaches, such as the adaptive LASSO (where coefficients are differentially penalized based on a prior estimate from a least squares or ridge regression fit, e.g. just using the LASSO selected variables and then using penalty weights = 1/abs(LASSO coefficients of 1st LASSO fit)) or relaxed LASSO (a simple solution being to do a least squares fit of the variables selected by the LASSO). In comparison to best subset, LASSO tends to select slightly too many variables though. Best subset selection is better, but harder to fit.

That being said, there are also efficient computational methods now to approximate best subset selection / $L_0$ penalized regression in a very stable way. One is using the adaptive ridge approach described in the [paper
"An Adaptive Ridge Procedure for L0 Regularization" by Frommlet & Nuel (2016)](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0148620) (this approach has a nice empirical Bayesian interpretation), as implemented in the [l0ara package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/l0ara/index.html) (there referred to as [broken adaptive ridge](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X17305067)) and my own L0glm package, still in development. Here one is approximating the non-convex best subset objective by a series of convex optimization problems, which then still has a unique solution at convergence. Another one is the approach for fast best subset selection as described in the [abess package](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.5555/3586589.3586791), which executes in [polynomial time](https://www.pnas.org/doi/abs/10.1073/pnas.2014241117). And there is also the [L0Learn package](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.04820) for sparse learning & approximating the L0 penalty, also potentially in combination with L2 penalty regularisation to deal better with collinearity. All are well worth checking out. Traditional combinatorial approaches to approximate best subset, such as used in the `glmulti`, `leaps` or `bestglm` packages I would not recommend - they do not scale to large problem sizes & tend to be unstable.

Note that also for best subset selection you'll still have to use either cross validation or some information criterion to determine what number of predictors gives you either the best prediction performance / explanatory power for the number of variables in your model (e.g. based on the [AIC](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322537/if-the-aic-and-the-bic-are-asymptotically-equivalent-to-cross-validation-is-it) or for high dimensional settings the GIC criterion) or approximates best the true support (e.g. based on [BIC or for high dimensional settings eBIC or MBIC](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577/is-there-any-reason-to-prefer-the-aic-or-bic-over-the-other)), which is essential to avoid overfitting.
The paper ["Extended Comparisons of Best Subset Selection, Forward Stepwise Selection, and the Lasso" by Hastie et al (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.08692) provides an extensive comparison of best subset, LASSO and some LASSO variants like the relaxed LASSO, and they claim that the relaxed LASSO was the one that produced the highest model prediction accuracy under the widest range of circumstances, i.e. they came to a different conclusion than Bertsimas, but that was also because they mainly looked at predictive performance and not at consistency of variable selection. So the conclusion about which is best depends a lot on what your aim is, e.g. achieving highest prediction accuracy, or achieving variable selection consistency and being best at picking out relevant variables and not including irrelevant ones or recovering the true support size most accurately. Ridge regression e.g. typically selects way too many variables but the prediction accuracy for cases with highly collinear variables can nevertheless be really good. If the true solution is really sparse there are cases where the optimal level of regularisation that results in optimal predictive performance and optimal support recovery coincide though - that is of course ideal. But of course it also depends how you would like to choose the tradeoff between Type I & Type II errors. Ideally you would like to have both a low number of false positives and a low number of false negatives, but that may only be possible with relatively large datasets & when the true solution is very sparse.

For a problem with many more cases than variables like you describe it is plain clear best subset selection is the preferred option though.

In my tests I found that an iterative adaptive ridge approach / broken adaptive ridge / L0glm approach has a series of advantages: (1) it nicely approximates best subset, (2) does so in a stable way (i.e. it has stable coefficient paths over the level of regularisation), (3) has good variable selection consistency (e.g. the union of selected variables over bootstrapped datasets typically converges quickly to a stable set, whereas LASSO would keep on adding spurious variables, which could only be mitigated by selecting the variables occurring in more than 80% of the bootstrap replicates, as in the [bolasso method](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1390156.1390161)), (4) deals well with collinearity and high dimensional problems (e.g. with several perfectly collinear variables in the model their effect would just be spread equally - it does [grouped variable selection](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X17305067) like elastic net), (5) resolves common problems one sometimes runs into with unregularised approaches (e.g. complete separation in logistic regression), (6) has the advantage that only variables with small or zero effect are removed and that variables with large effect will stay in the model and will be unbiased, implying that omitted variable bias will be small, (7) is fast and scales well to large problems with millions of variables (computational speed is similar to glmnet), (8) allows one to choose the optimal level of regularisation a priori based on what information criterion one would like to optimise, (9) allows one to do inference via bootstrapping for both low & high dimensional problems and (10) allows one to specify prior beliefs based on the starting values given (which correspond to the square root of the SD of the Gaussian prior implied in the first iteration of the algorithm) and the prior mean (normally zero, but can also be specified to be nonzero for particular parameters if nonzero centered ridge regression updates are used). Only in high dimensional settings with an extremely sparse true solution I found MCP & SCAD penalized regression to perform better (these can be fit using [ncvreg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ncvreg/index.html) or [ordinis](https://github.com/jaredhuling/ordinis)), but even that could be covered by using MCP or SCAD penalized regression estimates as warm start starting values in an iterative adaptive ridge L0glm approach, [in which case L0glm can find an even better solution still & remove some false positives](https://github.com/tomwenseleers/L0glm/blob/master/benchmarks/test_high%20dimensional2.R).

But all this is talking about particular approximations of best subset that are uniquely determined, and are calculated either using a nonconvex penalty (in MCP and SCAD) or as a sequence of convex optimization problems (in iterative / broken adaptive ridge / L0glm). Many best subset algorithms approach the problem as a combinatorial optimization problem, and they suffer from poor stability. That, combined with the high computational cost, is probably the reason many stay away from them. But given that in my tests iterative / broken adaptive ridge / L0glm models were superior to LASSO in terms of predictive performance, biasedness of the coefficients and support recovery, stable best subset approximations should imho receive a lot more attention. See e.g. here for [some examples and benchmarks that I made relating to the single or multichannel deconvolution of a blurred sparse spike train](https://github.com/tomwenseleers/L0glm/blob/master/benchmarks/benchmarks_single%20and%20multichannel%20plus%20comparison%20glmnet%20ordinis%20abess%20L0learn.R), where I compared some different approaches (`L0glm`, `abess`, `L0Learn`, `glmnet` & `ordinis`) (this is a problem where for single channel n=p, so in that sense a relatively small dataset, though with nonnegativity constraints on the coefficients), or a [high dimensional example (with n=500 and p=1000000 variables and 50 contributing variables, so with a very sparse solution and also with nonnegativity constraints) where nonnegative MCP penalized regression fit using `ordinis` or `L0glm` with MCP as initialisation performed very well](https://github.com/tomwenseleers/L0glm/blob/master/benchmarks/benchmarks_high%20dimensional2.R) & where in both cases these approximations of best subset performed better than LASSO, both in terms of predictive performance and in terms of support recovery / variable selection consistency (ending up with just a couple of false negatives & 1 false positive), whilst also scaling well to large problems. Both of those examples are ones with nonnegativity constraints on the coefficients, which is a situation that makes recovery of the best subset a lot easier, as it acts as an effective regularisation method in itself - in fact, under that circumstance a [hard thresholded version of the nonnegative LASSO](https://mayhhu.github.io/pdf/2018_L1-NNSO-Optim_ZHYW.pdf) outperforms plain nonnegative LASSO in support recovery and unconstrained LASSO in predictive performance, and even a [hard thresholded version of nonnegative least squares](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-journal-of-statistics/volume-7/issue-none/Non-negative-least-squares-for-high-dimensional-linear-models/10.1214/13-EJS868.full) would then outperform the plain LASSO.

Comment: What does "better" mean in the phrase "it is better than lasso"?

Comment: Why is best subset the same as using L0 penalty? Best subset selects the best subset (with the lowest validation error) among subsets of any size; at least that's what OP suggested in their question. L0 penalty requires the subset to be of size $k$ (that is defined by the regularization parameter $\lambda$); one can search for best $k$ using a validation set, and then it's the best subset of size of $k$ across all possible $k$... okay, now I see that it's the same :-)

Comment: Edited my answer a bit to give some more detail...

Comment: I don't think any of the answers are addressing the problem of stability.  Like stepwise and all possible subsets regression, `lasso` is notoriously unstable.  In other words if you were to bootstrap the entire process you'll find too much arbitrariness in the list of features selected.

Comment: Yes the variables selected by LASSO can be unstable, and this is even more so the case for best subset regression - elastic net regression is a little bit better in this respect - that tends to include far too many variables then, but selected in a more stable way, and can give better prediction accuracy under high collinearity. But a lot depends on what is the most important criterion for your application - prediction accuracy, the false positive rate of including irrelevant variables or the false negative rate of not including highly relevant variables...

Comment: @FrankHarrell With that Frommlet & Nuel iterative adaptive ridge regression approach to approximate L0 penalized regression it seems the selected set is really stable actually, as can be verified if you do it on bootstrapped data. If you look at the union of selected variables you very quickly converge on a stable set. Not so with best subset sought via a combinatorial approach though. And also not with LASSO - there that set keeps on growing. But the bolasso (where variables occuring in X% of the bootstrap replicates) has been suggested to select a stable best subset.

Comment: We know that the bootstrap selection frequency approach offers nothing new.  And I would like to see a strong simulation to show the probability that the adaptive ridge approach selects the "right" variables.  I'm dubious.  The needed information content is just not there in the data.  People even claim to be able to do feature selection with non-large N.  It takes N=300 just to estimate a **single** correlation coefficient.

Comment: @FrankHarrell It all depends on the sparsity of the true solution. I was looking at simulations now with n=500 and p=1000000 and the true solution having 50 contributing variables (with nonnegative coefficients) and iterative adaptive ridge warm-started with MCP being able to pick them out with just 1 or 2 false positives & false negatives. Nonnegativity constraints also help a lot of course. The probability to select the exact correct set will maybe not be that great - but it will be really close & the variables that it will kick out will be ones with very small coefficients...

Comment: I would love to see the method applied to this simulation experiment: slide 8 of https://hbiostat.org/talks/taiwan.pdf (code may be found [here](https://hbiostat.org/attach/lasso-EXPIRES-2023-08-13.Rmd) )

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks - will take a look & have a try! In the meantime here are a couple of examples for a specific deconvolution problem (single or multichannel) where the specific interest was to recover the correct support size & not just get optimal predictive performance: https://github.com/tomwenseleers/L0glm/blob/master/benchmarks/benchmarks_single%20and%20multichannel%20plus%20comparison%20glmnet%20ordinis%20abess%20L0learn.R. And high dimensional example here: https://github.com/tomwenseleers/L0glm/blob/master/benchmarks/test_high%20dimensional2.R. Sorry code not tidied up yet...

Comment: @FrankHarrell In these examples, both the predictive performance and the support recovery were better with these methods (which could be said to be a stable approximation of best subset) than with LASSO.

Comment: @FranHarrell In the logistic regression example you linked the dataset indeed is too small for accurate best subset identification (also using iterative adaptive ridge). But change the example to one with Gaussian noise & a high enough signal to noise rate or to binomial data or add positivity constraints & you would get reliable support recovery with L0glm, MCP/ordinis/ncvreg, abess or L0Learn. You had a slight mistake in the use of glmnet though as the coefficients from cv.glmnet were used whereas you should use that just to choose lambda & get the coefs from a glmnet fit on all the data.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into the cv.glmnet problem.  I don't feel that the example should be changed to test the methods, other than trying different sample sizes.  And this is a binomial data situation already.  Not clear why you'd want positivity constraints.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Well the probability to successfully pick the correct variable(s) are greatly aided if there are positivity constraints. Re binomial - so right now it's logistic data (0/1) but if you would make it binomial with a trial size per row in your dataset of say 100, the information content of your data would be a lot higher, making it a lot easier to pick out the correct variable(s). With Bernouilli data information content is quite limited....

Comment: @FrankHarrell If you were to do a similar plot for that Gaussian high dimensional problem that I linked with n=500 and p=1000000 and 50 contributing variables but with nonnegativity constraints, https://github.com/tomwenseleers/L0glm/blob/master/benchmarks/benchmarks_high%20dimensional2.R, you'd see that the accuracy & F1 score to recover the true support set with MCP or SCAD is very good, but not when using LASSO. So it's all very problem specific. Looking at one particular setting is not so informative...

Comment: This is very helpful.  Thanks for engaging in this.

Comment: @FrankHarrell FYI with code in the link you sent for that logistic regression problem this is what I get for plot of probability of variable to be selected by LASSO in function of real regression coefficient with NOBS=5000 and NP=500 - quite consistent then if coefficient is important enough: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ym5resjvsftzu6ra5qke7/harrell-lasso-NP-500-NOBS-5000.png?rlkey=q5idjoo55ifmjgwjx0tdfqgj7&dl=1. Main defect is variable still being selected with prob of ca 60% when true coef=0. That's what bolasso tries to rectify, keeping only vars selected in >80% of all bootstrap repls.

Comment: I see that the power for large true coefficients is much greater for the new procedure, but the high error rate for "no effect" variables is a severe problem for the method.  The bootstrap is just a bandaid here.  You've mainly shifted from one problem to another, which is in line with my suspicion that the data lack sufficient information for feature selection in general even for fairly large N.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Well this was just with LASSO & bolasso is indeed just a bandaid here. This is the output with NOBS=5000 and NP=500 if you use MCP (using ncvreg with default gamma): much better then for variables with no effect: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/8occ5bcwinstt9gahhcyn/harrell-mcp-NP-500-NOBS-5000.png?rlkey=1a49br825gflcpre56e2nl3ae&dl=1. It was indeed the case that for the logistic case at least sample size was just too low for reliable variable selection. Not so surprising given limited information content of binary data. Positivity constraints would help though.

Comment: Very informative Tom - thanks for trying that.  Very similar results to plain lasso.  The sample size of N=5000 is larger than most biomedical research "omics" studies.  As you alluded, N=5000 or smaller really requires a high-information response variable to be successful, but most omics studies don't use those.  It would be interesting to see what a Bayesian approach with horseshoe priors would do here.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Yes similar to lasso, but without that problem that for zero true coefficients it would still select them in >60% of all cases. So that problem at least is fixed & wouldn't need a posthoc fix like bolasso. But yes, for variable selection to be successful with small sample sizes one typically needs a high-information response, a high signal to noise ratio, a sparse true solution or box or positivity constraints on the coefficients. To select variables with small effect one usually needs large sample sizes. Haven't tried horseshoe or spike & slab priors. Harder to scale up also....

Comment: @FrankHarrell I am not sure by the way that selecting variables occurring in more than X% of all fits on bootstrapped data would just be a bandaid. I can well see it as a generic method that would improve variable selection consistency for any sparse learning method, and where the X just needs to be adjusted in function of the method, e.g. 90% works well for Lasso, https://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/fbach_bolasso_icml2008.pdf, while for MCP, SCAD or iterative adaptive ridge 20% works well (hence needing far fewer bootstrap replicates to yield a stable set).

Comment: @FrankHarrell It's similar to Meinhausen's stability selection, except that it uses all the data (never quite understood why stability selection splits the data in 2 & uses random splits instead of resampled data).

Comment: Bootstrap selection frequencies are a bandaid because they are ruined by collinearities and tell you nothing new that things like p-values don't already tell you.  And when they are used to lessen false positives they will increase false negatives.  It's a zero sum game.

Comment: @FrankHarrell For LASSO maybe they are - but for iterative adaptive ridge / L0glm I was not so sure - there the union of selected variables after bootstrap converges very quickly on a stable set. Using the set occurring in >20% of bootstrap replicates converges even faster, often after <10 bootstrap replicates & will decrease the FPR while not significantly increasing the FNR for variables with nonzero effects. And to get p values via bootstrapping doing 10000 bootstrap replicates on a small pre-selected stable set of variables is fast, while doing it on the complete dataset would be slow.

Comment: @FrankHarrell See here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/617990/inference-for-high-dimensional-models-based-on-running-a-glm-on-the-union-of-s for a concrete example.

Comment: I am not convinced by that.  Looking at what information the bootstrap is using, it's not finding any new information that wasn't already available to the original fitting method so it can only benefit you if it hurts you equally in the other direction.   I know that this is a largely subjective opinion but I've seen the bootstrap selection frequency to have no added value in the unpenalized case.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Well in example here, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/617990/inference-for-high-dimensional-models-based-on-running-a-glm-on-the-union-of-s, if one were to fit a regular GLM on a stable set of variables selected by (1) the union of variables selected by L0 glm fit on 100 bootstrapped dataset or (2) those occurring in >30% of the fits on bootstrapped data then the latter would recover the correct support & would produce the least biased coefficients while the 1st option would introduce bias due to slight overfitting. And doing analysis unpenalized not an option since n=p

Comment: I'll keep thinking about this.  One other reservation is the arbitrariness of the selection threshold - one more free tuning parameter that I'm not convinced we need.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Yes that selection threshold indeed would require tuning, but one could consider it just one more hyperparameter of the fitting method, and tune it in the same way that one would tune other hyperparameters such as alpha in glmnet or gamma in SCAD/MCP, e.g. using the value giving the smallest cross validation error or based on value that would minimise AIC or BIC or eBIC or MBIC.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd have to see a major advantage to make it worth adding a tuning parameter that according to the underlying method used should not be necessary.  Another take on the problem. If you computed a Bayesian posterior probability of a feature having a non-trivial effect, for each feature, you'll find the vast majority of features have a probability in the uncertain range 0.1 - 0.9 meaning that the data lack sufficient information for deciding whether or not to select the feature.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Yes L0glm / iterative adaptive ridge method in principle should not need it, except perhaps to guard against occasional numerical issues. In your example it would still select features with zero effect with a non-negligible probability of ca 10%, so that could potentially be improved. For LASSO there could be a big benefit. Hard thresholding has been suggested as an alternative, again with a tuned threshold, https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-journal-of-statistics/volume-7/issue-none/Non-negative-least-squares-for-high-dimensional-linear-models/10.1214/13-EJS868.full

Comment: @FrankHarrell I think our difference in perspectives just come from you considering datasets with insufficient information to reliably select features whereas I am looking at problems where they can be identified very reliably (e.g. in the deconvolution problems I linked, which arise e.g. in GC & GC/MS data analysis problems) & the whole point is to approximate the correct support as best as possible...

Comment: Yes.  You must be analyzing exceptonally high signal:noise ratio datasets without continuous Y whereas in biomedical research we have quite low S:N and often have binary Y.  With high S:N everything works better.