# Model selection in simultaneous ARMA-GARCH modeling without AIC

Tags: arima, model-selection, aic, garch

How does one determine the mean model and the variance model in simultaneous ARMA-GARCH modeling without using AIC?

Rather than two step look at ACF/PACF of residuals squared of ARMA to specify the GARCH mean model order, and find p,q in ARMA of the series squared then use `rugarch` how does one find the specifications in ARMA-GARCH?

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer?

Comment: it seems I didn't understand what arma-garch was, and wanted to figure out how to do it, and now I realized what's arma-garch, and the answer isn't what I was looking for because I asked for something I didnt understand.

Comment: Well, your goals may have changed, but perhaps the answer does a good job addressing the question as it is :)

Answer (score 1):

Model selection should be guided by an explicit goal. Different goals may justify different models.

Among information criteria, there are several alternatives AIC such as BIC, HQIC and more. They have different optimality properties, and which one is the most relevant depends on your modelling goals.

Aside from information criteria, you can do time-series cross validation to optimize a criterion of your choice on the validation data. While dissimilar on the surface, cross validation and information criteria are related and may converge to the same selected model in large samples (["If the AIC and the BIC are asymptotically equivalent to cross validation, is it possible to dispense with a test set when using them?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322537)).

Alternatively, you may seek statistical adequacy. Briefly, you would build a rich enough model such that the data would not be in conflict with it. In case of ARMA-GARCH we are talking about i.i.d. standardized innovations as proxied by standardized residuals. That rules out nonzero autocorrelation and ARCH patterns, among other things. You would then try to simplify it without breaching the assumptions. See Spanos ["Probability Theory and Statistical Inference: Empirical Modeling with Observational Data"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1244803) (2nd Edition, 2019) section 15.6.3 or any of his papers that contain a section on his probabilistic reduction approach (a few references can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303887)). Similar ideas are at the core of automated model selection algorithms (both for the conditional mean and the conditional variance) available in the [`gets`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gets/gets.pdf) package in R by Genaro Sucarrat.